# NumberFormatException: invalid long:"name"

Tags: android

I am getting this error in my android app. When I am going for auto suggestion, I got this error. Why I am getting this error. Please Help me.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "name"
at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
at android.database.MatrixCursor.getLong(MatrixCursor.java:255)
at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:220)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildImeCompletions(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1123)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1082)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:971)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$800(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PopupDataSetObserver$1.run(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1268)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please check "name" field is long or string..?

Comment: That field is String.

Comment: Is that string contains always text or numbers only.

Comment: @bharat Both string and number.

Answer (score 0):

This will crash since it isn't a `long`

```
Long.parseLong("name")
```

It has to be something like this

```
Long.parseLong("12345567890")
```